# I need 2 column layout in WordPress pages

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, multiple-columns, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm looking to get the page located here https://themissingpieceonline.com/website-management-subscription/ in 2 column format.
Have tried the built-in column format but that's not worked...
Here's the coding....

```
    <p style="text-align: left;">[fullstripe_subscription form="webmanbasic"]</p>

<h4><strong>Weekly Updates</strong></h4>
<h4 style="text-align: left;"><strong>Monthly Site Backups</strong></h4>
<h4 style="text-align: left;"><strong>Performance Check</strong></h4>
<h4 style="text-align: left;"><strong>Security Check</strong></h4>
<h4 style="text-align: left;"><strong>Client Reports</strong></h4>
<h4 style="text-align: left;"><strong>Plus…</strong></h4>
<h4><strong>3 months of access to our project management software!</strong></h4>
```

Want to get the form and text side by side.

I have already tried some WordPress plugins but nothing has worked. Can you help me....[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nfNIE.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

```
<style type="text/css">
#wrap {
   width:600px;
   margin:0 auto;
}
#left_col {
   float:left;
   width:300px;
}
#right_col {
   float:right;
   width:300px;
}
</style>

<div id="wrap">

    <div id="left_col">
        <p style="text-align: left;">[fullstripe_subscription form="webmanbasic"]</p>
    </div>

    <div id="right_col">
        <h4><strong>Weekly Updates</strong></h4>
        <h4 style="text-align: left;"><strong>Monthly Site Backups</strong></h4>
        <h4 style="text-align: left;"><strong>Performance Check</strong></h4>
        <h4 style="text-align: left;"><strong>Security Check</strong></h4>
        <h4 style="text-align: left;"><strong>Client Reports</strong></h4>
        <h4 style="text-align: left;"><strong>Plus…</strong></h4>
        <h4><strong>3 months of access to our project management software!</strong></h4>
    </div>

</div>
```

Make sure that the sum of the colum-widths equals the wrap width. Alternatively you can use percentage values for the width as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create two div sections like below example.

```
**Column HTML**
<div class="left">left content</div>
<div class="right">right content</div>

**Column CSS**
.left, .right {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 50%;
}
```